# How should I spend extra gold?

Tags: league-of-legends

I finished a game of League of Legends where I earned 25000g.  At the end, I had ~6000g unspent, as I already had the boots I wanted and 5 top-tier items.  What am I supposed to do with all the rest?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main thing to purchase would be **Elixirs**. If you purchase an elixir whilst you have all 6 items occupied, you'll instead automatically consume the elixir and gain its benefit. The fact that the benefit persists through death is merely icing on the cake for what is otherwise just some extra stat bonus that you don't need item slots for. With 6000g, you can buy a very long duration of elixir benefits.

A less savorable option would be to swap out items for other options. Perhaps to account for a shift in how the battle is going, or to try out a new strategy. Usually, if you're swimming in gold, though, you don't *need* a new strategy. Nevertheless, sometimes you think that swapping for, say, a more push-oriented item in order to just end the game, for example.

Comment: Did not know you could buy them while full, thought you needed to have a free spot.  You make it sound like you can buy multiple and the duration will stack(?)

Comment: Nick, I'm pretty sure @Grace means you can buy multiple elixers: one each of fortitude, agility, and brilliance (Or whatever they're called. Red, green, and blue elixers) and then replenish them each time the duration runs its course.

Comment: Buy Oracle's anytime you die too, to destroy any ward you see.

Comment: The other thing you can do is cycle items. In short, buy the Guardian Angel for its passive (revival on death), and as soon as that has been used, sell it off for a more useful item. Once the 5 minute cooldown is over, sell your new item to buy a new Guardian's angel. Sure, it's expensive, but at this stage of the game, what else are you going to do?

Answer (score 4):

When I have that much gold and 3 elixirs on me, I sell my boots and buy onw of the following items:

- Trinity Force(if I dont have) or Phantom Dance for AD champions
- Lich Bane for AP champions

For my gameplay these items are more useful than boots, because ussualy I dont need to rely on movement speed **in late game**, these items can give me enough movement speed to finish the game, plus they add more chance to win a team fight IMO.

(when Im playing a tank I switch the boots for FoN or Trinity (if I bought FoN earlier))

Answer (score 1):

With 6000g unspent, I hope you were a hard carry. 
If you are a support, or maybe a tank, you may stop at 5 items, then buy 5 purple ward each time you back. It might be very useful rather than buy a sixth item.